# Выражать неудовольствие работе? Как выкрутиться, чтоб не громоздить турусов на колёсах?

Tags: управление

> Кто никогда не выражал своё неудовольствие работе телеоператора, не
>   дающего крупный план любимого киногероя в реальной жизни?

Неудовольствие работой? Недовольство работой, а?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Неудовольствие** - *чувство/ощущение* **от кого/чего** или **по отношению к кому/чему**. Можно быть недовольным чем/кем, в частности, испытывая неудовольствие (от/по отношению/в связи с), и выразить **недовольство** этим **чем/кем** *кому*, но **не** *чему*. Испытав неудовольствие, можно не просто поведать оператору о своём *неудовольствии от* его работы (можно и это ощущение выразить, мол худо мне было от твоей работы, ну да бог с тобой), а и выразить ему *недовольство* его работой (я за что деньги плачу?), чтобы тот впал, наконец, в *недовольство* собой.

> **Неудовольствие** от работы [*ощущение*], **недовольство** работой [*отношение*].
>
> Выразить то или другое (от/чем) - **кому**, но **не** чему.

**P.S.** "Никогда" - лишнее слово, от вопроса во 2 лице (вы никогда не... ?). Если надо "подраматичнее", то лучше "хоть раз (в своей жизни)", а так выходит наоборот, вяленая риторика (может, на кого и была проруха в этом вопросе).